# AVCapture not working well with retina screen

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession, retina-display

I am trying to use AVCapture in my app to capture the image and post it to a server, but I have a problem with this framework:

With a normal iPhone screen, this framework work very well, but with a retina screen, the AVCamera doesn't work well: The iPhone's video is zooming in to the target higher than the camera, so my camera is too close to the object I want to shoot.

I researched this and saw that the retina device's default camera has this problem too. The image camera and the video camera have different scale zooming, and the AVCamera probably uses the video camera so the target is higher than the image camera. But I want to take the picture with the image camera with AVCapture, how can i do it?